# How to synchronize two folders in Bash?

Tags: bash, rsync

I am writing a short script. One functionality is synchronizing two folders. Now I have two variables with directories to two different folder: `DIRECTORY_1` and `DIRECTORY_2`. In both folders are files and other folders. I need to synchronize these folder to have all files in both folders. For example:

1. In `DIRECTORY_1` I have file1, file2, file3 and folder1
2. In `DIRECTORY_2` I have file4, file5, file6 and folder2
3. I need comment after which I will have in both directories files1-6 and folders1-2.

I was trying rsync command but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: If `dir1/file1` and `dir2/file1` differ, which one will be overwritten? (not my downvote, btw)

Comment: Then dir1/file1 is crucial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ mkdir dir1
$ mkdir dir2
$ touch dir1/file1 dir1/file2 dir1/file3
$ mkdir dir1/folder1
$ touch dir2/file4 dir2/file5 dir2/file6
$ mkdir dir2/folder2
$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- file1
|   |-- file2
|   |-- file3
|   `-- folder1
`-- dir2
    |-- file4
    |-- file5
    |-- file6
    `-- folder2
$ rsync -a dir1/ dir2
$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- file1
|   |-- file2
|   |-- file3
|   `-- folder1
`-- dir2
    |-- file1
    |-- file2
    |-- file3
    |-- file4
    |-- file5
    |-- file6
    |-- folder1
    `-- folder2
```

I guess `rsync -d dir2/ dir1` would be next?

Answer (score 1):

Likely not the most efficient, but this would do the trick:

```
comm <(ls DIR1) <(ls DIR2) -23 | while read f; do cp -r DIR2/$f DIR1; done
comm <(ls DIR1) <(ls DIR2) -13 | while read f; do cp -r DIR1/$f DIR2; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use unison, it's a real folder synchroniser (such as Dropbox or Mega did).

https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

Mac installation with brew:

```
 brew install unison
```

I used this command:

```
unison -auto /path/folder1 /path/folder2
```

Moreover, and most important to me, if 2 files have the same name, it replaces with the most recent version.